# Where does TeXworks hide temporary files?

Tags: texworks, filesystem-access

I am running TeXWorks under Windows 10.

If I've made some changes to a .tex file, but have not yet saved those changes, then there surely must be a temporary file someplace where TeXworks keeps the current (but not-yet-saved) version of the file.  Presumably it automatically deletes that file when I exit.

I'd like to write a DOS script that copies that file to another directory every ten minutes or so.  (This will save my changes in case of a crash, without actually overwriting the original file, which I might not be quite ready to do.)

**Question 1:**  Where does TeXworks hide that file?

**Question 2:**  Is there some better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I know nothing about texworks but why do you assume there is such a file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  Now that you ask, I realize that my assumption was rash, and therefore my question quite likely has no answer.